# How to add colors to a country using basemap

Tags: python-2.7, colors, matplotlib-basemap

i'm having troubles adding colors to my world map using basemap in python.
i've a list with country names and frequencies
for example:

```
Usa 304
France 120
Italy 23
Spain 152
```

i've created a colorbar with three different colors (red, yellow, orange). the yellow indicates the area of 300-400, so when usa have a frequency of 304, I would like to have usa to be yellow.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import colors

m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
    llcrnrlon=-160,urcrnrlon=160,resolution='c')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries(color='black')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
m.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='aqua')

#Colorbar

zvals = np.random.rand(100, 100) * 10

# make a color map of fixed colors
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['white','yellow','orange','red','purple'])
bounds=[0,20,30,50,200, 400]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

img = plt.imshow(zvals, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower',
                cmap=cmap, norm=norm)


plt.colorbar(img, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, boundaries=bounds, ticks=[0 ,20, 30, 50, 200, 400])


plt.title('Imdb Top250 feq countries')
plt.show()
```

so my question is, how do i combine add colors to the countries after their frequencies. 
Is the longtitude and latitude neceassary?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a shapefile of the actual country boundaries, which you can then add to your Basemap instance by calling the `readshapefile` method:

```
m.readshapefile("/path/to/your/shapefile", "countries")
```

If you don't have this, you can get it from e.g. [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/version2).

Next you need a way of connecting the information in the shapefile with the dataset on frequencies you have. The call to `m.readshapefile()` as performed in the example above will return two objects which are then callable from the `Basemap` instance: `m.countries` will be a list of the actual coordinates of the country borders, while `m.countries_info` will contain be a list of dictionaries, with one dictionary for each country containing, amongst other things, the country's name.

Thus, you will have to figure out which part of `m.countries_info` you can use to map the shapes in `m.countries` to your underlying data set. How this will play out exactly will depend on both the exact info in your data set and the keys in the `*_info` dictionaries coming from the shapefile.